# Site wide https with Laravel 4

Tags: php, https, laravel, laravel-4

I am curious to find out how people are doing site wide https with links and forms. I am familiar with URL::secure for generating a form link. It looks like you can pass https to a route to force https. Does this mean I have to set https on every route definition?

Comment: I was thinking about this myself the other day, I have not tested anything but my first though was to wrap everything in a route group and force https over that group.

Comment: I haven't tested, but you might be able to accomplish this via the base url config item (setting the base url per environment - "https" in production).

Comment: @fideloper Where are you setting this setting? I checked config/app.php and I see a URL option but it's only for the artisan command line.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do it using your web server? I think it's safer and you don't have to do anything else on your application.

This is my configuration for apache:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    #Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain.com/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
```